# Getting subtype from nested type

Tags: scala

I don't see the way to get subtype of nested type , is it possible ?

```
type IN[A,B] = {
  type X = A
  type Y = B
}

trait INH[IN[A,B]] {
  type X = IN#X
  type Y = IN#Y 
}
```

But this doesn't compile...

**UPDATE**
I'm going to expand this case:

There are some classes : A,B,C,N - which are States , and i want to implement path dependable objects :

1. **C** - must be initialized only from **A** OR **B**
2. **D** - must be initialized only from **A** OR **B** OR **C**

```
abstract class State

trait UN[T <: |∨|[_, _]] {
  type U[I] = T#λ[I]
}

case class A() extend State
case class B() extend State
case class C(state: State) extend State with UN[(A |∨| B)]
case class D(state: State) extend State with UN[(A |∨| B |∨| C)]
case class Z() extend State
```

So Curry Howard definitions of union type :

```
type ![S] = S => Nothing
type !![S] = ![![S]]
type ∨[T, U] = ![![T] with ![U]]
type |∨|[T, U] = { type λ[X] = !![X] <:< (T ∨ U) }
```

So i'm trying to make something like that , but without success:

```
case class C(state: State) {
   def test[T <: State](t:T)(implicit ev: (A |∨| B)#λ[T]) = {}
   def apply[T <: State](state: T)(implicit ev: (A |∨| B)#λ[T]) = C(state)
}

val a = A(); val b = B(); val z = Z()
val ca = C(a); val cb = C(b)
ca.test(a) // compilation OK
val cz = C(n) // that shouldn't compile but it's
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do it following way:

```
trait IN[A, B] {
  type X = A
  type Y = B
}

trait INH[T <: IN[_, _]] {
  type X = T#X
  type Y = T#Y
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from talex is correct, but note that this kind of type projection over abstract type members will be disallowed in Scala 3 (it won't be there before 2020).

Your use-case seems a bit odd, why are you not simply declaring `IN` as

```
trait IN {
    type A
    type B
}
```

You could then access `A` directly as `IN#A` or, better and allowed in Scala 3, going through an instance `in` of `IN` as `in.A`.

If you want to able to constrain `A`, `B` or both in a concise way, you can use type refinement and define an alias:

```
type INWithSpecificA[+AA] = IN {
    type A <: AA
}
```

Same goes with `B`. I personally find that this kind of design is more flexible than talex's suggestion.

Comment: `why are you not simply declaring IN as` - My guess is that OP has created this to work around type-erasure.